# Disable a UIButton without having fade effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

When I disable a button using `Button.enabled = NO;` the button fades out.

Is it possible to prevent it?

I want to disable the functionality of the button but I want it with the same look.

Comment: Why? Its not very user friendly to disable user interaction of a button and have no way of letting the user understand that they can't press it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using

```
[Button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the user to interact with button using this

```
yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```